# What would cause SharePoint not playing videos?

Tags: video, sharepoint

Recently the videos in our production sharepoint 2016 server stopped playing.

If we try to view videos from client desktop, 'Media failed to load' is displayed. This was tested using both IE11 and Edge, and Silverlight add-on is installed for IE11.

If I log on to the server and try to play the videos there, 'Install Silverlight' is displayed at the top of the video frame.

On our development farm, the videos still plays OK. I checked that Silverlight is installed on the development server, but missing from the production server. I believe it would've been installed on the production server before as well as both servers would have been configured nearly identical. But as Silverlight is no longer supported, the download link from Microsoft's official site no longer works, and I don't want to just download from other sites that I've never heard of.

So initially I thought this would caused by Silverlight being unintentionally uninstalled by someone, as there seemed to be some update to both servers the day before the issue was found. But after I setup a new SP2016 farm in my Hyper-V, I see that by default Silverlight is not installed, and SharePoint can still play video without Silverlight. Now I think Silverlight would have been installed by Windows Update at some point in time.

I looked at Event log and ULS log on the production server and could not find any related error messages. Needless to say I have googled for quite a few hours and had found nothing that would help. Some said it was caused by permission issue, and some simply said SharePoint does not require Silverlight to play videos. So right now I'm quite stuck on why SharePoint is failing to load the videos now and hope someone may know the possible causes of the problem, or point me to the direction of how to troubleshoot this.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Kind regards

### **Update:**

User notified me that the issue started occuring after she deleted a video from the library. (Let's call this Video A).

She deleted Video A because after she uploaded a new video (Video B), and tried to play Video B, Video A was played instead. Then regardless which video in the library she tried to play, it always ended up with Video A being played. So she tried to delete Video A. With Video A deleted, SharePoint still tried to play Video A, so 'Failed to load media' was displayed!

I tried to create a new library and uploaded some videos into it and they played nicely. The site had customized pages but both original and new video libraries would inherit the customization I think. And I don't see any additional webparts placed into the original library's videoplayerpage.aspx, so don't know why this library had suddenly played up like this...

### **Update 2**

Further information provided by the user. Seems like while she had the videoplayerpage.aspx opened to play a video, she went on to edit the page and updated the media link for the media webpart. This caused the webpart would only play that one video from then on!

New question: Is there a way to reset the videopalyerpage.aspx for an assets library?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could reset a broken videoplayerpage.aspx was to create a new assets library, then use SharePoint Designer and edit the videoplayerpage.aspx in advanced mode, copy the whole content of the file, and paste it into the broken videoplayerpage.aspx in the original library.

Now the videos can play as normal again.